# How to upload Image to Hosting directly without php in Android?

Tags: android

I'd like to upload images to my own hosting, I don't want to use upload services . Please can you suggest any library to be implemented.

Comment: Why does this have the android label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a FTP Client (like  [this one](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) )to upload directly to your hosting, but anyway you'll need to send the file name and the location of the file via php...

Comment: Brother, do you have any ftp idea deals with android ?

Comment: Check this link ( http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php ), here is a nice explanation of how to use it.

Comment: Best and perfect, But a little insecure :) .. Worked perfectly before 4.0, I use thread after on version 4.0